# jQuery Toggle on Hover Multiple Instances

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Currently hovering over one div causes all three to toggle at once. Trying to figure out how to get only the item being hovered over to toggle at that time. While I could give each a unique ID and duplicate the javascript rules for each, I would assume there is a cleaner way without having to add additional unique classes since there will be many more than the three in the demo.

Code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNdggv

```
$( ".product" ).hover(function() {
  $( ".product-caption.odd" ).toggle( "slide",{direction:"left"},500);
  $( ".product-caption.even" ).toggle( "slide",{direction:"right"},500);

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use  `$(this).find()` to get the product caption of the hovered element

[Demo](http://codepen.io/jcastillo/pen/KpvOKK)

```
$( ".product" ).hover(function() {
  $(this).find(".product-caption.odd" ).toggle( "slide",{direction:"left"},500);
  $(this).find(".product-caption.even" ).toggle( "slide",{direction:"right"},500);

});
```

Comment: Perfect! I knew it would be something simple. Thank you. Will accept as soon as it lets me in 8 minutes.